# How to format series labels of a BIRT chart by script

Tags: charts, birt

I have a chart report displaying indicator values over time. This indicator is a report parameter and can represent either a percent (%) or a currency ($) value.

Here is an example with a percent type:

[image]

Now i need to change the format number of datapoint labels depending on the type of the selected indicator. In BIRT designer i defined percent format by default:

[image]

The indicator type is extracted from a dataset and stored in a persistent global var, so that it can be accessed in chart scripts.

In a data field of a crosstab the format could be changed in "onCreate" event with something like:

```
 this.getStyle().numberFormat="$ #,###";
```

But in chart scripts i can't find out a way to change the format number dynamically. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in openText forums [here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/36939-how-to-format-series-labels-of-a-chart-by-script/). We can format datapoint labels in the chart event "beforeDrawDataPointLabel". In this example below, the expected number format (for instance "$ #,###") is stored in a global variable "numberFormat":

```
importPackage(Packages.java.text);
nf = new DecimalFormat(getGlobalVariable("numberFormat"));

function beforeDrawDataPointLabel( dph, label, icsc ){ 
  label.getCaption().setValue(nf.format(dph.getOrthogonalValue()));
}
```