# How to change data point color of Birt line chart for those points which are below marker line through script

Tags: charts, birt

I am using Birt line chart where I want to achieve something like this [How to format series labels of a BIRT chart by script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404320/how-to-format-series-labels-of-a-birt-chart-by-script?rq=1)
I want to show the points which are below marker line in red color just like this link has mentioned.

Comment: What all things you tried before?

Comment: I got code for highchart to use 'zone' within series, but it is of no use in script part

Comment: @PiyushZalani i have also use series.marker.fillcolor which is applying to entire series instead of threshold value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `fillColor` of `marker`.
Code Snippet:

```
beforeGeneration: function(options)
{
    var throughTargetPercent = this.getReportVariable("through_target_percent"); 

    for(var i = 0 ; i < options.series.length ; i++){
        var data = options.series[i].data;
        var len = data.length;
        for (var j=0; j < len; j++){
             if(data[j].y < throughTargetPercent) {
                data[j]= {
                    y: data[j].y,
                    marker: {
                        fillColor: "yellow" 
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
},
```

Hope it helps!